# jQuery dataTables search - Set search filter to get only matches that starts like search value

Tags: jquery, search, filtering, datatables

If you search in data tables a word, it will found anywhere in a word.

Example: Search of "b" in table:

```
 banana
 subway
 sub
```

Will return all 3.

How could i set to get only "banana" if i type "b" in search field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dare to assume you are thinking about jQuery dataTables (have replaced the ambigious [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) tag with the correct [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) tag too).

You can create a custom filtering function if you want to filter on what the column data begins with, and not search / filter on the entire strings. Like this, which also is case insensitive :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        //$('#example_filter input') is the default #example filter box
        var term = $('#example_filter input')
                .val()
                .toLowerCase();

        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            value = data[i]
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase();

            if (value.indexOf(term)==0) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        return false;
    }
);
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v1yguqLz/**

**Note** : This should per the documention and how dataTables worked in "the old days" be a task for a [regular expression search](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()), but I cannot get even the simpliest regular expression example to work, neither by `table.search()` nor `table.column().search()`.  Have tried with *1.10.0* through to *1.10.5* (recent version). I guess this has something to do with this bugreport -> **https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/341** and backwards compability.

On the other hand, if you just want to filter on what the column data begins with, then a custom filtering function is the perfect solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have a separate search field for one of the columns and here's my solution for begins-with search:

```
    vm.searchForLocation = function() {
        vm.dtInstance.DataTable.column(2)
            .search("^"+vm.locationCode, true, false )
            .draw();
    }
```