# datatables default regex to search only start

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables

Hi have the java script for datatables as below, How can define it so that the search is done only for start values, eg : [ hello, hello_all, all_hello] is there and my search key word is  "hel" i should get filter of [hello,hello_all].

```
 $('#example').DataTable( {
           data: new_data,
           dom: '<"top"fB>rt<"bottom"ipl>',
           buttons:['csv'],
           search :{"bSmart": false,
                      "regex":true},
           columns: [
                { title: "Action" },
                { title: "Input" },
                { title: "State" },
                { title: "Completed" },
                { title: "Project" },
           ],
          "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]
       });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery dataTables search - Set search filter to get only matches that starts like search value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359594/jquery-datatables-search-set-search-filter-to-get-only-matches-that-starts-lik)

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation:
https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html
The filterColumn function is what you looking for I think.
I hope that helps.

Gruesse

```
function filterGlobal () {
$('#example').DataTable().search(
    $('#global_filter').val(),
    $('#global_regex').prop('checked'),
    $('#global_smart').prop('checked')
).draw();
}

function filterColumn ( i ) {
$('#example').DataTable().column( i ).search(
    $('#col'+i+'_filter').val(),
    $('#col'+i+'_regex').prop('checked'),
    $('#col'+i+'_smart').prop('checked')
).draw();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable();

$('input.global_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
    filterGlobal();
} );

$('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
    filterColumn( $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column') );
} );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a separate search field for one of the columns and here's my solution for begins-with search:

```
vm.searchForLocation = function() {
    vm.dtInstance.DataTable.column(2)
        .search("^"+vm.locationCode, true, false )
        .draw();
}
```